# python multiprocessing, make instance per process and reuse it

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, worker

I'm using pytesseract to do some ocr with a multiprocessing approach.

The approach looks the following:

```
tess_api = PyTessBaseAPI()
Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(execute)(image) for image in images)
```

having the function:

```
def execute(image):
    tess_api.SetImage(image)
    text = tess_api.GetUTF8Text()
```

this will lead into a concurrency problem as Worker 1 could override the image before Worker 2 is executing gettext()

The idea is now to have per worker one instance of `PyTessBaseAPI`.
The main idea would be to do something like:

```
tess_apis = [PyTessBaseAPI(), PyTessBaseAPI(), PyTessBaseAPI(), PyTessBaseAPI()]
```

and then hand over `tess_api[0]` to the worker 0 but I don't know how I could do the connection between the worker and the instance.
Any suggestions, or what would be a better approach?
As I have thousands of images I don't wan't to create instances inside the execute function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Pool(initializer=...)` to initialize the Tesseract object once per worker process before they start reading their job queue.

```py
tess_api = None

def initialize_worker():
    global tess_api
    tess_api = PyTessBaseAPI()  # initialize a copy for this instance

def execute(image):
    tess_api.SetImage(image)
    text = tess_api.GetUTF8Text()

def main():
    with multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=initialize_worker) as p:
        for result in p.imap_unordered(images, chunksize=10):
            # ...
```

This will only work if you're using actual processes; if you're using threads instead (which might work, considering Tesseract is C and would release the GIL), you could use `contextvars`/`threading.local`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that

Answer (score 1):

`Pool(initializer=...)` can work as mentioned. However, if you want to do anything more complex, I'd suggest using [Ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray).

Then it an be expressed as follows.

```
import ray

ray.init()

@ray.remote
class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tess_api = PyTessBaseAPI()

    def execute(self, image):
        self.tess_api.SetImage(image)
        return self.tess_api.GetUTF8Text()

# Create several Worker actors.
workers = [Worker.remote() for _ in range(4)]

# Execute tasks on them in parallel.
result_ids = [worker.execute.remote(image) for worker in workers]

# Get the results
results = ray.get(result_ids)
```

You can read more about [Ray in the documentation](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Note that I help develop Ray.

Comment: ok thank you, just a question. Where and how would you pass the array? so you use `worker.execute.remote(image)` but where would you use the array images?

Comment: The array (which is called `image` in this example), is passed in when you call `worker.execute.remote(image)`. That call passes the image to the remote worker process, and the remote worker process then runs the `execute` method on it. Does that make sense? If you have a list of images, then it would be more like `[workers[i].execute.remote(images[i]) for i in range(len(workers))]`.

Comment: Ok I took a deeper look into it and saw I cannot use it in my case. I have to run the script on a windows server and use python 3.6. And as I have read without migrating to unix, which is not possible in my case, or downgrade to python 2.X I cannot make use of ray. Otherwise I would have loved to use it.

Comment: Makes sense. Ray supports Python 2 and 3, but Windows support is still in progress.